# Execute all files in a list

Tags: shell-script, find, executable

I have a source tree which, when `make` is run, produces several executables named "001", "002", and etc. I'm trying to write a script which will find all of these executables in my source tree, and then execute them. I have this so far:

`find build/ -type f -executable | ack --nocolor "\d{3}$"`

Which lists the executables that I want to execute correctly.

My question is, how do I then run all of them? I thought perhaps some combination of `xargs` and `exec` would do it, but `exec` seems to try replacing the current shell with the command, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ find build/ -type f -executable | ack --nocolor "\d{3}$" |
while read prog
do
    "$prog"
done
```

Comment: I think @1_CR's answer is cleaner to *just execute the files*, but I'm accepting this because it turns out that it's useful to be able to do other stuff inside the `while` besides just executing the file, and it's trivial to extend this version. Thanks! :)

Comment: @CmdrMoozy, you don't need to step outside `find` in order to loop. For example `find build/ -type f -name '*[0-9][0-9][0-9]' -executable -exec bash -c 'for f; do cksum "$f"; done' _ {} +`

Answer (score 4):

This may work

```
find build/ -type f  -executable -exec sh -c 'exec "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Or to filter to just the `001`, `002` .. files

```
find build/ -type f -name '*[0-9][0-9][0-9]' -executable  -exec sh -c 'exec "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: The OP want to filter the result of `find` before execute it.

Comment: @Gnouc, I am not sure if he's using `ack` for listing or for filtering. Anyways, i'll add a filter

Comment: `ack` is basically a nicer version of `grep` - so it's mostly for filtering. This build system produces some other files that are marked executable besides the actual compilation results.

Comment: @CmdrMoozy and Gnouc, added filtering

Comment: +1 because you solved the problem using only `find`. Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you explain what is the benefit of `-exec sh -c 'exec "$1" _ {}'` w.r.t. just `-exec {}`?

Answer (score 1):

One of the things `find` is good at is selecting files that match criteria,
so you can use it to pick out the files whose names consist of three digits. 
And then you can use this simpler form:

```
find build -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9]" -type f -executable -exec {} ";"
```

And you might be able to use `-regex '.*/\d{3}`
if you can find the right `-regextype` to go with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
find -type f -name '00[123]' -exec env - {} \;
```

Add in whatever environment you want to declare for the different executables. Maybe `2>/dev/null` if there are non-executable `00[123]` files lying around and you don't want to hear about it.